# Do nobot and notop options overwrite a template style?

Tags: sas

I have the following code

```
proc template;
define style styles.test;
parent=styles.analysis; 
replace output from container / 
cellpadding=1pt
cellspacing=0pt ;
end;
run;

ods html file="C:\users\owner\desktop\class.html" (nobot notop) style=styles.test;
proc print data = sashelp.class;
run;
ods html close;
```

But it does not implement my `test` style at all.

However, when I remove `(nobot notop)`, everything works fine.

How can I implement my style AND get rid of the top and bottom parts the way `(nobot notop)` does ?

Comment: In order to answer this properly we need a little more detail about 'Why?' you need to do this?  Also, how familiar are you with how HTML/CSS works?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I need to get table in `html` form. I am including it to my website using `jquery  .load` . The problem is that SAS provides `cellspacing=3pt` and I do not need that kid of formatting. So i tried to overwrite it with `proc template`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing a difference in the appearance of the table is due to the `notop` option.  The appearance of ODS output (generally) relies upon CSS classes.  The `notop` option will prevent the definition of these classes from being included in the .html file that is being created.

You can see how the CSS definitions are excluded from the file by running it with and without the option enabled.  Open the files in notepad to view the contents rather than in a web browser.

```
ods html file="C:\example1.html" (nobot notop) style=styles.test;
proc print data = sashelp.class;
run;
ods html close; 

ods html file="C:\example2.html" style=styles.test;
proc print data = sashelp.class;
run;
ods html close;
```

The good news is that you can output the CSS into its own file using the `stylesheet=` option:

```
ods html file="C:\example2.html" style=styles.test stylesheet="c:\mycss.css";
proc print data = sashelp.class;
run;
ods html close;
```

This will create a file `c:\mycss.css` that contains just the stylesheet definitions that you need.  You can then upload this file onto your webserver (or copy it to the same folder as your html) and within the HTML documents  tags add the following line to include it:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
</head>
```

You can then use the version of the `ods html` statement that just outputs the table and you should be done.  Combining everything we've discussed above, you can put it altogether into a single statement like so:

```
ods html file="C:\example2.html" (nobot notop) style=styles.test stylesheet="c:\mycss2.css";
proc print data = sashelp.class;
run;
ods html close;
```